# 3d orthographic rotation of 2d texture using html canvas transformations

Tags: canvas, rotation, orthographic

I've looked all around and can't seem to find anything specific to what I'm trying to do.

As the title implies, I just want to simulate 3d orthographic rotation using `CanvasRenderingContext2D.setTransform()`-no perspective, just orthographic rotation.

What I've tried so far:

Rotation around a 45* vector in the 2D plane is simple enough, I'm using

`setTransform(scaleFactor, skewAngle, skewAngle, scaleFactor, 0.5*width, 0.5*height)`

Just as it seems, center of the canvas, same `x` and `y` skew gives the right rotation, but I'm having trouble determining the scale factor since skewing goes to infinity when the rotation angle (skewAngle) approaches 90*.

What I need:
Rotation and appropriate scaling around ANY vector in the 2D plane, e.g. based on perpendicular vector to (mousePosition - centerCanvas) - flipping toward (or away) from the mouse cursor.

If anyone can break this down for me, I would greatly appreciate it.  If there is an article that explains this specifically, that'd be great too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I work it out.  Not too hazardous.

I was doing it the hard way with `setTransform()`.

Here's a simple example:
    // using processing.js
    background(0);

```
// rotate by 5 degrees each frame
a = (a + 5) % 360;
var c = Math.cos(a * Math.PI / 180);

// processing.js provides mouseX and mouseY, width and height
var dx = mouseX - 0.5*width,
    dy = mouseY - 0.5*height;

// orthogonal to mouse position from center position
var b = Math.atan2(-dx, dy);

var ctx = this.externals.context;

ctx.save();
ctx.translate(0.5 * width, 0.5 * height);
ctx.rotate(b);
ctx.scale(1, c);
ctx.rotate(-b);
text("G", 0, 0);
ctx.restore();

ctx.save();
ctx.scale(1e-1, 1e-1);
// text size is 100px, position is centered at x, y
text("angle: " + a, 250, 50);
ctx.restore();
```